# Plotly Funnel Chart Example Shows Zero Width Shapes

Tags: python, plotly

I have copied and pasted the exact code on the plotly example page [here](https://plot.ly/python/funnel-charts/) in a Jupyter notebook - with the exception that I am running in offline mode so my import statements look like this:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly import graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode()
```

The resulting plot has funnel shapes with no width. 
[image]

Is the example code broken? I thought it had something to do with defining the `shape` and `path` variables, but printing those values they look reasonable.

Or, seems unlikely, but could offline mode be messing something up?

Complete code from the linked example is below:

```
values = [13873, 10553, 5443, 3703, 1708]
phases = ['Visit', 'Sign-up', 'Selection', 'Purchase', 'Review']
colors = ['rgb(32,155,160)', 'rgb(253,93,124)', 'rgb(28,119,139)', 'rgb(182,231,235)', 'rgb(35,154,160)']
n_phase = len(phases)
plot_width = 400
section_h = 100
section_d = 10
unit_width = plot_width / max(values)
phase_w = [int(value * unit_width) for value in values]
height = section_h * n_phase + section_d * (n_phase - 1)
shapes = []
label_y = []

for i in range(n_phase):
        if (i == n_phase-1):
                points = [phase_w[i] / 2, height, phase_w[i] / 2, height - section_h]
        else:
                points = [phase_w[i] / 2, height, phase_w[i+1] / 2, height - section_h]

        path = 'M {0} {1} L {2} {3} L -{2} {3} L -{0} {1} Z'.format(*points)

        shape = {
                'type': 'path',
                'path': path,
                'fillcolor': colors[i],
                'line': {
                    'width': 1,
                    'color': colors[i]
                }
        }
        shapes.append(shape)

        # Y-axis location for this section's details (text)
        label_y.append(height - (section_h / 2))

        height = height - (section_h + section_d)

# For phase names
label_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[-350]*n_phase,
    y=label_y,
    mode='text',
    text=phases,
    textfont=dict(
        color='rgb(200,200,200)',
        size=15
    )
)

# For phase values
value_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[350]*n_phase,
    y=label_y,
    mode='text',
    text=values,
    textfont=dict(
        color='rgb(200,200,200)',
        size=15
    )
)

data = [label_trace, value_trace]

layout = go.Layout(
    title="<b>Funnel Chart</b>",
    titlefont=dict(
        size=20,
        color='rgb(203,203,203)'
    ),
    shapes=shapes,
    height=560,
    width=800,
    showlegend=False,
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(44,58,71,1)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(44,58,71,1)',
    xaxis=dict(
        showticklabels=False,
        zeroline=False,
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        showticklabels=False,
        zeroline=False
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Please add the complete code you were using to your question. The link might be become updated and then no one knows to which code you were referring to.

Comment: @elphz So, I tried the code you provided, the output is coming properly, maybe you need to update plotly, can you try that? the code works fine!

Comment: Not a plotly update, but turned out to be Python 2 vs. 3 issue. I'm still using Python 2 so `unit_width = plot_width / max(values)` is zero, which was the root of the issue